# Prism v4 - Loading only some Modules from directory based on Role - MEF

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, mef, prism-4

What I'm trying to accomplish:

- Load Views / Services based on the current user's Role while having all dlls in a single directory
- Views can be created multiple times (separate windows)

I currently have my modules loading from a directory using the following code:

```
protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog()
{
    base.ConfigureAggregateCatalog();

    AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Bootstrapper).Assembly));
    AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(AutoPopulateExportedViewsBehavior).Assembly));

    // Load modules from folder
    // Create Modules folder if it doesn't exist
    string modulesFolder = "Modules";
    if (!Directory.Exists(@".\" + modulesFolder))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(@".\" + modulesFolder);
    }
    AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(modulesFolder));
}
```

I've tried searching around for examples of what I'm trying to do and have found them for MEF, but none with MEF + Prism so I'm wondering if its the same idea or if Prism has something built in as well.

I've seen that for regular MEF the best solution (please correct me if this is incorrect!) is to create a Custom Export Attribute ([MEF Export Metadata](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Exports%20and%20Metadata&referringTitle=Guide)) such as:

```
[MetadataAttribute]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple=false)]
public class UserLevelAttribute : ExportAttribute
{
    public UserLevelAttribute() : base(typeof(IModule)) { }
    public UserLevel User { get; set; }
}

public enum UserLevel    {
    Basic,
    Administrator
}
```

Is this the correct way or is there something in Prism that helps with this? What is the best way to only load the modules for the userlevel? In regular MEF I'd do an `[ImportMany]` and `Lazy` load them, is this still valid with Prism, if so, where should I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm actually looking at role management myself today and from a post on the Prism forum from one of the developers ([Guido Maliandi](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/265488)):

> The subject of authentication and authorization isn't supported in
>   Prism out of the box.

So we have to roll our own, but Guido Maliandi has done a blog post showing one way of doing ["Authentication and role based authorization in Prism v4"](http://blogs.southworks.net/gmaliandi/2011/10/authentication-and-role-based-authorization-in-prism-v4/) which utilizes a service to get a list of Module Names for the Module Manager to load in.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look, its in Silverlight but hopefully should be helpful in getting me on the right track.

Comment: I'm still fairly new to Prism and Mef myself but after looking through the example I gave you I think your regular Mef solution should work just fine. Register all your Modules' assemblies with the AggregateCatalog as you are and then after knowing what role your user is, LoginSuccess(), use the imported meta data to figure out what modules should load. Then call the IModuleManager.LoadModule(string moduleName).
Edit: (Dang enter key)
Look in the LoginViewModel, LoginSuccess. I believe you could skip the GetAllowedModules by using the metadata your exporting

Comment: So I got the example working, its just you need to have a config file or database service to return the modules. And like you we want to load dynamically discovered modules, so I think the modules themselves need to contain the role management.

Comment: Did you get this working without having to hard code the references? If so could you post some of the code you used? I'm still having some problems with it. Thanks!

Comment: Sadly its company code, but I plan on doing an implementation at home (hopefully this weekend). What problem are you having getting it working? The only module reference you need is the ModuleInfo (assembly name, location, version#, load type) to add to the ModuleCatalog, from there you use the ModuleManager.Load(string xapName). Looking at your code again I think you might actually want to rip out your directory modules in another function. The Aggregate I think directly loads it (good for the login module).
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921099%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx

Comment: Yeah the problem I'm having is trying to get it to dynamically see the modules and determine which ones to load. I can get it working with hardcoded module names (even with `DirectoryCatalog`), but I'm not sure how to get the MEF Metadata when using Prism... maybe its not even possible as I haven't been able to find any examples of people doing it during my hours of searching. If you have any examples of how to do get them dynamically please let me know, its been driving me crazy :)

Comment: @Suiko6272, Can you please provide some more info on your R & D